# How to Sum / Count two different columns in one query SQL?

Tags: sql-server-2008, count, sum, multiple-columns, difference

Im new here and Im stuck with a query.
To sum up, we have a Table "Teams" which has two columns, teamID and name.
Then we have another Table "Matches" that has, among other things, matchID, localTeamID, visitorTeamID,localTeamGoals,visitorTeamGoals....etc etc.
So the query requires the following: "Return the name of the teams, indicating the number of matches played as local, and the number of matches played as visitor, as two different columns, in a single query, not allowed to use Cursors".

The problem is, you need the team names, so when you do the join between Matches and Teams on, lets say, localTeamID = teamID, you only get the local matches...so in order to get the visitors aswell...you join again the same teamID with visitorTeamID....but there is my problem, for each local match, i get all the visitors matches...

How can I obtain the right result like

```
Team          LocalMatches     VisitorMatches
Real Madrid             4                   5
Manchester              5                   4
```

Note that "sums" or "counts" in the query may differ.
Thanks in advance, I hope anyone can help me here.

Comment: Note that for each row in Matches table, you can only see which team played vs other team (local vs visitor), so to know how many matches a team has as local and as visitor, you gotta count/sum every row you find for each team as local and as visitor...but its difficult to count it as when you find a row with the visitor ID of that team, you wont get the local id and viceversa....

Answer (score 1):

You can use subqueries like this:

```
select Name as Team
  ,(select count(*) from Matches where localTeamID = teamID) as LocalMatches
  ,(select count(*) from Matches where visitorTeamID = teamID) as VisitorMatches
from Teams
```